# asp:RadioButton - Radio button click working fine in IE, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

### ASP.Net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbABC" GroupName="samp" Text="ABC" CssClass="fl_left"
        onclick="clickStreamForLCW('rdbABC-Linetype', 'radio', this);return LaunchApplyChangesLTC(this);"
        Checked="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdbLineType_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbXYZ" CssClass="fl_left" GroupName="samp" Text="XYZ"
        onclick="clickStreamForLCW('rdbXYZ-Linetype', 'radio', this);return LaunchApplyChangesLTC(this);"
        Checked="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdbLineType_CheckedChanged" />
```

### JavaScript

```
function LaunchApplyChangesLTC(sender) {
    if ($("#dVApplyChangesPopUpforLineType") != null) {
        try {
            if (document.getElementById("hdnSelectedLTCount") != null) {
                var hdnLineCount = document.getElementById("hdnSelectedLTCount");
                if (hdnLineCount != null) {
                    if (hdnLineCount.value > "4") {
                        $("#dVApplyChangesPopUpforLineType").jqm({ modal: true });
                        $("#dVApplyChangesPopUpforLineType").jqmShow();
                        $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) { }

    }
    __doPostBack(sender.id, "");
}
```

I have 2 Radio buttons, ABC selected by default. When i select XYZ, a popup should be shown.

This is working fine in IE, but not in other browsers. In Other browsers, if i select XYZ, Popup is displayed, but XYZ radio button not getting selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing `return false` after showing popup, which, among others prevent default action. Remove it and the selection should go thru.

If you're doing it to prevent postback - just set `AutoPostBack="false"` for that button and if needed - postback via `__doPostBack` - looks like you're doing it now already in other place

Comment: Glad the solution was useful. Good luck in further developement